# Combine two json array as key-value in mysql and create one json object

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

I have two JSON array fields in MySQL like this:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["apple", "banana", "coconut"]
```

Now I want to combine them into one JSON object like this:

```
{"a":"apple", "b":"banana", "c":"coconut"}
```

Is there any MySQL function for this?

Comment: MariaDB or MySQL, which's yours?

Comment: My server is MySQL 8.

Comment: then, using `JSON_TABLE()` is simpler and better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this in a simple way.

- Unnest the two JSON structures using `JSON_TABLE()`.
- Join the two tables together.
- Construct the appropriate JSON objects and aggregate.

The following implements this logic.  The first CTE extracts the keys.  The second extracts the values, and finally these are combined:

```
WITH the_keys as (
      SELECT j.*
      FROM t CROSS JOIN
           JSON_TABLE(t.jsdata1,
                      '$[*]'
                      columns (seqnum for ordinality, the_key varchar(255) path '$')
                     ) j
     ),
     the_values as (
      SELECT j.*
      FROM t CROSS JOIN
           JSON_TABLE(t.jsdata2,
                      '$[*]'
                      columns (seqnum for ordinality, val varchar(255) path '$')
                     ) j
     )
select json_objectagg(the_keys.the_key, the_values.val)
from the_keys join
     the_values
     on the_keys.seqnum = the_values.seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0387b88e7f2d372b50c86f390f8e91d) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this is quite generalizable (you can add more elements to the rows).  You can readily adjust it to return multiple rows of data, if you you have key/value pairs on different rows, and it uses no deprecated functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract by `JSON_EXTRACT()` function due to the index of each element within the arrays along with the contribution of row generation through use of a table from `information_schema`, then aggregate all results by using `JSON_OBJECTAGG()` returning from the subquery such as

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(Js1,Js2)
  FROM
  (
   SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata1,CONCAT('$[',@rn+1,']'))) AS Js1, 
          JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata2,CONCAT('$[',@rn+1,']'))) AS Js2, 
          @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
     FROM tab AS t1
     JOIN (SELECT @rn:=-1) AS r
     JOIN information_schema.tables AS t2
 -- WHERE @rn < JSON_LENGTH(jsdata1) - 1 #redundant for MariaDB, but needed for MySQL
  ) AS j
```

where

`'["a", "b", "c"]'` is assumed to be the value of the column `jsdata1` and

`'["apple", "banana", "coconut"]'` is assumed to be the value of the column `jsdata2`

within a table(`tab`) containing only one row inserted.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=43db5d8bbcca44a0c70a4d7a95b38c88)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it for every row in a table like this:

| id | jkeys | jvals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ["a", "b", "c"] | ["apple", "banana", "coconut"] |
| 2 | ["x", "y", "z"] | ["xigua", "yangmei", "zucchini"] |

Normalize the data using [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) for both arrays and join them on the *ordinality* column.

```
select t.id, k.o, k.jkey, v.jval
from t
join json_table(t.jkeys, '$[*]' columns (o for ordinality, jkey text path '$')) k
join json_table(t.jvals, '$[*]' columns (o for ordinality, jval text path '$')) v
  using(o)
```

| id | o | jkey | jval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | apple |
| 1 | 2 | b | banana |
| 1 | 3 | c | coconut |
| 2 | 1 | x | xigua |
| 2 | 2 | y | yangmei |
| 2 | 3 | z | zucchini |

Then you can group by the primary key (`id`) and collapse the key-value pairs into one object using [`JSON_OBJECTAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg):

```
select t.id, json_objectagg(k.jkey, v.jval) as j
from t
join json_table(t.jkeys, '$[*]' columns (o for ordinality, jkey text path '$')) k
join json_table(t.jvals, '$[*]' columns (o for ordinality, jval text path '$')) v
  using(o)
group by t.id
```

| id | j |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a": "apple", "b": "banana", "c": "coconut"} |
| 2 | {"x": "xigua", "y": "yangmei", "z": "zucchini"} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5-ycmogH)

Answer (score -1):

The basic way for it using [JSON functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/) like:

```
select JSON_OBJECT(
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a, '$[0]')), JSON_EXTRACT(b, '$[0]'),
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a, '$[1]')), JSON_EXTRACT(b, '$[1]'),
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a, '$[2]')), JSON_EXTRACT(b, '$[2]')
) result from tbl;
```

[SQL sandbox](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=0867983f19b2e57594250d77697e9194&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Comment: This code is not performing when I don't know the JSON array size.